# How to add button in manifest xml

Tags: xml, joomla, joomla3.0, joomla-extensions

I want to add a button with link into my Joomla module/plugin config area.

Given image have some form field but I want to add one more option as a button . when user click that button then they go to to another link.

[image]

Comment: More info is needed.

Comment: Sounds like you need to build your own custom field. You can look up tutorials for that or take a peek at an already existing plugin, like the tinymce editor.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this easily, creating a "custom form field type".

https://docs.joomla.org/Creating_a_custom_form_field_type